# My friend from Texas wants to go on holiday to the UK, but has no passport. Will she need to make one?

Tags: passports, international-travel

Say what, I ain’t got a picture to post lol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: A passport is only required if you fly or catch a boat.  If you drive or walk from Texas to the UK then there is no need for a passport.  Also, voting to close, because WTF?

Comment: @Doc A passport is used to cross borders, however you enter. I use my passport to enter countries I **walk** into (as opposed to fly or sail).

Comment: @dda I suspect that it was a joke considering how tricky it is to walk or drive from the US to the UK.  Walking into the UK is only feasible if you start in the Republic of Ireland or maybe through the tunnel from France (be careful of the trains).

Comment: Then again the phrase "A passport is only required if you fly or catch a boat." is quite generalizing and misleading :-) The main purpose of a passport sure ain't taking a plane of boat...

Comment: @dda This is common mechanism for creating a joke. As you don't see it intuitively lets the try the academic appraoch. a) A generally sensible statement ("only if you fly or take a boat" is juxtaposed with an absurdity "walking from Texas to the UK". b) The absurdity now makes the inital statement meaningless. --> A seemingly meaningful statement made meaningless but adding an adsurd scenario --> This is considered funny.

Comment: Making a passport is quite hard to do right, so US citizens mostly just pay the Department of State to make one for them.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a passport is required for US citizens to visit the UK.